# Why are all members of the Kuja tribe born as women?

Tags: one-piece

On chapter 515 they mentioned all Kuja Tribe women always give birth to females.

How is this possible? Is there any explanation about this?

[image]

Comment: The same picture you use gives you the explanation: 'mysteriously', welcome to the world of anime magic :)

Comment: In One Piece, the story revolves around Monkey D. Luffy, showing his tremendous luck with unexpected situations. This is just one of those extra details, i.e. if men too were born on the island, he would be like just another normal person to them and would not receive such favors.

Comment: I agree with @Dimitri mx: I would like to have a place on earth like this!

Comment: Maybe its because its is just happening biologically. Their bodies are like that. Also, could be the place and environment around them and the climate as well.
Thats what I think so.

Comment: well my question is how does the Kuja tribe conceive? All I know is men are not allowed in the island, and the ones that come in are killed.

Comment: So they don't bring back boys to the island. What's the big deal?

Comment: I think you guys misunderstood, with child is a common expression meaning pregnant, here it doesn't mean "with a child" and they conceive children outside the island with men from the rest of the world, but then return to give birth, without the fathers.

Answer (score 5):

No explanation is ever given beyond the word "mysteriously" but it isn't as ridiculous as it sounds.

In the real world, environmental factors such as the temperature and diet of the mother during pregnancy can affect the likelihood of a boy or a girl being born. Of course it rarely gets above 55-45 one way or the other, but in the unique environment of Amazon Lily it is possible that the odds of having a baby girl is completely overwhelming, to the point where no boy has ever been born on the island.

Comment: What if "mysteriously" means that they simply returned *only* with the girl babies? You know, because males are not allowed, not even boy babies I presume...

Answer (score 0):

Unless the one piece author/s clarify the existence and origin of the Kuja tribe, there would be no accurate answer for this question. It happens most of the time in any anime and one piece is not an exception, let's just wait for any episodes where this tribe will be explain even more. For the meantime the succinct explanation of the Kuja tribe are as follows:

The Amazon Lily:
http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Amazon_Lily

The Kuja Tribe:
http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kuja

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer would of course be "Magic" or anime logic.

However, when we look at the issue from a logical standpoint, we don't need to look at the tribe, but at the foreign countries, since the gender of the newborn is determined by the winning sperm, which either carries a female chromosome (X) or a male chromosome (Y).

Maybe the males in the foreign country only produce female sperm. Sperm production is affected by enviromental factors but this is unlikely, there'd be reports of that foreign country having female births (unless their females travel and get impregnated somewhere else as well). Keep in mind it's entirely possible that those reports could exist but the reader never gets told of any of this.

Most likely is that the tribe actually gets males born, but they are promptly killed (and no record of them is kept), much like [real Amazon tribes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazons) did it.

Comment: To correct you, women have XX chromosome pairs while men have XY pairs, to my knowledge there is no such thing as "female sperm" as that would indicate that at fertilization of the egg the gender of the child is decided however as @Qiri has said there are factors _during_ pregnancy which can sway the chance of a particular gender

Comment: Female sperm reffers to sperms carrying a X chromosom, which is one half of the female chromosom set (the other comes form the egg, guranteed to be X), which indeed determines the gender of the child at the point of fertilization.

Comment: I don't know anything about female or male chromosome work but I believe Eiichiro Oda never kill anyone for a reason like that, he hardly kill anyone for any reason.

Comment: Other ways to achieve similar results would be simply abdaboning the male babies (Leaving the nature do the dirty job) or give birth at the foreigin country and leave the male babies there. @Maroon, added a link for clarification.

Comment: Who knows? maybe some of their tribes are Hermaphrodite, and others are just born to be normal, like the Snake Princess and the previous queen. If you remember they both suffer Love Sick.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this might not be true. There may have kids being born as boys but due to some reasons the boys did not lived. In short, the elders are trying to prevent from boys being alive. I believe this is somewhat similar to what happened with Vincent(Hiei from Yu-yu Hakusho) wherein he was an outcast because of the tradition of having only female to live in their village.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe while they're out in the world, they did give birth to boys but was like 'oop! You're a boy; orphanage for you' and just only took home the girls. Remember, them getting pregnant requires them to leave the island OF WOMEN to go into the world OF MEN. So only people who left would know for sure. Who says they have to tell anybody they had a boy? Or that they were pregnant at all?